# Keep getting error messages in ghostscript when using the documented ghostscript syntax

Tags: windows, ghostscript

I am new to ghostscript and I cannot figure out the syntax. Whenever I try the simplest of commands ex -h or -? I get an error and I have tried them in all sorts of combinations.

```
    GPL Ghostscript 9.05 (2012-02-08)
Copyright (C) 2010 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.

GS>-h
Error: /undefined in -h
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
  %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval-
-   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --n
ostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   .runexec2   --nostr
ingval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval
--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1166/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
Current file position is 3


GS>gs-h
Error: /undefined in gs-h
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
  %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval-
-   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %loop_continue   --n
ostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   .runexec2   --nostr
ingval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval
--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1166/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 5
```

Comment: how did you copy the text? I can't use right mouse

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're inside the PostScript interpreter and what you're entering isn't PostScript.

You need to run the exe on the command line with -h (there are a couple of binaries in the distribution, one will respond correctly).

Comment: Not sure if I follow, are you referring to the cmd's inside the lib file in the ghostscript installation? ex: ps2pdf.cmd -h

Comment: You should be able to gswin32c.exe -h

Comment: Cheers Alex! You were a great help!

Comment: Any idea how to do this in Linux? I can't figure out how to open ghostscript outside of the postscript interpreter

Answer (score 8):

What I tried is as follows:

The directory of Ghostscript installation on my system (the path to the file "**gswin32c.exe**"):

C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.10\bin

Then I opened windows command prompt (our normal command prompt window) and did this:

**C:\>cd C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.10\bin**

then..

**C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.10\bin>gswin32c.exe -h**

there you go....

the help instructions got displayed, means everything was well and good !